# Custom orderBy funcition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso criar uma função para fazer um `ordeBy` customizado em um `ngRepeat`, mas não estou conseguindo pensar lógica que devo usar para realizar a ordenação.

O requisito da ordenação da lista é a seguinte:

> Os recursos devem ser exibidos por ordem crescente da data de
>   apresentação. As impugnações devem ser exibidas abaixo do recurso
>   associado por ordem crescente da data de apresentação.

Segue um array de exemplo, onde a associação entre Recursos e Impugnações é dada pelo campo Número:

```
[{
'numero': '1',
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-26T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'RECURSO'
}, {
'numero': '2',
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-26T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'RECURSO'
}, {
'numero': '3',
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-28T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'RECURSO'
}, {
'numero': '1',<br>
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-28T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'IMPUGNACAO'
}, {
'numero': '4',
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-27T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'RECURSO'
}, {
'numero': '1',
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-29T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'IMPUGNACAO'
}, {
'numero': '2',
'dataApresentacao': '2016-01-29T00:00:00-02:00',
'tipo': 'IMPUGNACAO'
}]
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Guillherme, ao formatar sua pergunta, use o [markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) disponibilizado pelo site.

Comment: Tentou fazer alguma coisa? É mais produtivo te ajudar se pudermos analizar seu código, assim dá pra dar respostas mais eficientes e você aprende mais no processo. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

A resposta é: você não precisa de um `orderBy` customizado.

O `orderBy` aceita mais de um campo para ser ordenado, sendo ele reverso ou não.

Exemplo:

```
<div ng-repeat="dados in listaArray | orderBy:['primeiro','segundo']"> </div>
```

Para o seu método, você pode utilizar algo semelhante:

```
<div ng-repeat="dados in listaArray | orderBy:['dataApresentacao','numero']"> </div>
```

Lembrando que para inverter a ordem, basta adicionar o sinal de negativo ao nome do campo, exemplo: `-dataApresentacao`

Comment: Agradeço a dica @CelsomTrindade ! Mas não deu totalmente certo, segue link para conferir: https://jsfiddle.net/a2a2uLjx/12/ Os itens do tipo Impugnação de número 4 e 5 deveriam estar em baixos dos itens do tipo Recurso de número 4 e 5 suscetivamente.

Comment: Mas você não terá como fazer isso se deseja manter a ordem por data. Deste modo ele está ordenando primeiro por data. E depois ele ordena pelo tipo. Ou seja, dentro os valores da data 28, os valores do tipo Recurso estarão à frente do tipo impugnação, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/a2a2uLjx/13/ Isso infelizmente é uma limitação que não tem como contornar, pois você deve ou organizar pela data, ou pelo nome, ou pelo nome dentro daquela única data, entende? Veja um exemplo mais elaborado: https://jsfiddle.net/a2a2uLjx/14/